# Error:(1, 0) Method hash in class com/android/repository/api/Downloader has illegal modifiers: 0x9

Tags: java, android, gradle

I keep having this error in my Android studio and i it prevents me from building or working on my app. 
Error:(1, 0) Method hash in class com/android/repository/api/Downloader has illegal modifiers: 0x9

Comment: What does the method declaration look like?

Comment: The thing is that the error seems to be coming from the Android plugin in gradle. And I don't know the location of the said error  on the project or studio library

Comment: The thing is that the error seems to be coming from the Android plugin in grade.

Comment: @LoganKulinski i dont understand what is  going on as every project i create with my android studio gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution,  you just have to change your JRE location in your studio,  you need to download the latest jdk 1.8 and it would be fixed and if you currently running a jdk 1.8 change the location to an older version- say jdk1.6+ and restart your studio,  after that change it back to your current jdk,  then restart your studio and wolla just like magic,  the catche causing the errors would be cleared then you can continue coding....